# Changing single contour svg image fill color in QML

Tags: svg, qml

I have made a single contour .svg cursor (basically a triangle curved at the bottom) without any fill, and I want to be able to change its fill color. I can't just make few different svgs for this, due to fill color being picked by user.

QtGraphicalEffects library is not supported since Qt6, so all I could find on this topic was of little use. The solution for this might be to just drop my svg over a colored rectangle, but then I'll have to mask out the area outside of my cursor to make it transparent(or vice-versa), and I'm not sure if it's even possible. I also found some shader-based solutions but none of then seem to work for my case (might just be me being new to QML)
SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #414141;
        stroke-width: 44px;
        fill-rule: evenodd;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path id="Pointer_1" data-name="Pointer 1" class="cls-1" d="M300.291,48.248L556.347,560.4s-127.234-47.825-255.133-47.825c-128.157,0-256.979,47.825-256.979,47.825Z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MULTIPLE EDITS]

Firstly, the latest builds of Qt6 do support QtGraphicalEffects via Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtgraphicaleffects5-

The approach I prefer to use is to leverage the fact that most components have an `icon` property which has a built-in mechanism for recoloring an SVG. You set the following properties:

- icon.source
- icon.width
- icon.height
- icon.color

By creating two SVGs we can use the above approach to control the fill and stroke independently.

The typical component I use is `Button`, but, I strip off the default `Button` UI/UX and just leverage from the `icon` property as follows:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    SplitView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        orientation: Qt.Horizontal
        Item {
            SplitView.preferredWidth: parent.width / 2
            SplitView.fillHeight: true
            Item {
                 anchors.centerIn: parent
                 width: parent.width * 8 / 10
                 height: parent.height * 8 / 10
                 Button {
                     anchors.centerIn: parent
                     visible: fillCombo.currentText !== 'none'
                     background: Item { }
                     icon.source: "shape-fill.svg"
                     icon.width: Math.min(parent.width, parent.height)
                     icon.height: icon.width
                     icon.color: fillCombo.currentText
                 }
                 Button {
                     anchors.centerIn: parent
                     visible: strokeCombo.currentText !== 'none'
                     background: Item { }
                     icon.source: "shape-outline.svg"
                     icon.width: Math.min(parent.width, parent.height)
                     icon.height: icon.width
                     icon.color: strokeCombo.currentText
                 }
            }
        }
        Item {
            SplitView.fillWidth: true
            SplitView.fillHeight: true
            ColumnLayout {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                Label {
                    text: qsTr("Stroke")
                }
                ComboBox {
                    id: strokeCombo
                    model: [ "lightsteelblue", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue" ]
                }
                Label {
                    Layout.topMargin: 20
                    text: qsTr("Fill")
                }
                ComboBox {
                    id: fillCombo
                    model: [ "none", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// shape-outline.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
  <path stroke="red" stroke-width="44" fill="none" d="M300.291,48.248L556.347,560.4s-127.234-47.825-255.133-47.825c-128.157,0-256.979,47.825-256.979,47.825Z"/>
</svg>

// shape-fill.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
  <path stroke="none" fill="black" d="M300.291,48.248L556.347,560.4s-127.234-47.825-255.133-47.825c-128.157,0-256.979,47.825-256.979,47.825Z"/>
</svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Alternatively, another approach is you can build your SVG as a data uri by adding a `"data:image/svg+xml,"` prefix to your SVG string. Because you're using a data uri, you can make a function that generates the SVG based on use input:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    SplitView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        orientation: Qt.Horizontal
        Item {
            SplitView.preferredWidth: parent.width / 2
            SplitView.fillHeight: true
            Image {
                 anchors.centerIn: parent
                 width: parent.width * 8 / 10
                 height: parent.height * 8 / 10
                 source: todatauri(getsvg(strokeCombo.currentText, fillCombo.currentText))
                 fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            }
        }
        Item {
            SplitView.fillWidth: true
            SplitView.fillHeight: true
            ColumnLayout {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                Label {
                    text: qsTr("Stroke")
                }
                ComboBox {
                    id: strokeCombo
                    model: [ "black", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue" ]
                }
                Label {
                    Layout.topMargin: 20
                    text: qsTr("Fill")
                }
                ComboBox {
                    id: fillCombo
                    model: [ "none", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function todatauri(svg) {
        return "data:image/svg+xml," + svg;
    }
    function getsvg(stroke, fill) {
        return `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #414141;
        stroke-width: 44px;
        fill-rule: evenodd;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path id="Pointer_1" data-name="Pointer 1" class="cls-1" stroke="${stroke}" stroke-width="44" fill="${fill}" d="M300.291,48.248L556.347,560.4s-127.234-47.825-255.133-47.825c-128.157,0-256.979,47.825-256.979,47.825Z"/>

</svg>
`;
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for. You see, I have a hollow triangle as a cursor, and using this method I can recolor the contour of the triangle, but not the inner part which I was referencing to as "fill", the svg itself has a fill property. I've edited my question to show.

Comment: Thanks, that makes the question clearer. I've reworked the answer to show two solutions to your problem. One involving two SVGs and still using the icon property approach. The other involves data uri. I've used both approaches in my own applications.